# twitter typeahead only trigger in the beginning, never trigger again until reload the page

Tags: twitter, typeahead.js

Whenever input the words into the twitter typeahead, it should allow me to remotely query the city.However, when I type the words in the first time, it triggers immediately. but after the first time, no matter how much I type into the typeahead, it never triggers again.

What is more,  `url:'/city?n='+$('.typeahead').val()`,  the server always receives the request with url on ' /city?n= ', so it seems  $('.typeahead').val() doesn't work though the input filed has value in it.

```
   <input class="typeahead" name="city" type="text"  style="width:400px" placeholder="Search cities..." >

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
   remote:{
        url:'/city?n='+$('.typeahead').val()
        ,timeout: 2000
        ,cache:84000
        ,rateLimitWait:1000 
     }  
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

try use the typeahead.js %QUERY wildcard to send query

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    remote:{
        url:'/city?n=%QUERY',
        timeout: 2000,
        cache: 84000,
        rateLimitWait: 1000 
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Question:** The reason why your typeahead does not work after the first query is because you might have made a mistake on server side, or client side, which crashed the page. Look into console if your request is being made each time or not and if the server is processing each request or not.

**For your second question**, I found [this bug reported in typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/863) that mentions that `$('.typeahead').val()` returns `undefined`. That might be the reason why your URL is not getting dynamically set.

try `$('.tt-input').typeahead('val')` instead.

`.tt-input` is the class inserted by the typeahead plugin.